# MySQL 5.7 : subquery as Table

Tags: mysql, create-table

I am trying to save some subquery into a table on MySQL 5.7, But I get a syntax error when I do:

```
create table total as
    SELECT s.col1,
        COUNT(id) AS num_id
    FROM myTable as ess
        inner join otherTable as s on ess.id1=s.id 
    GROUP BY s.col1;

select * from total
```

How Can I do this?

When I do

```
select version()
```

I get

```
5.7.25-28-27-log
```

Comment: I have tried it an d it runs alo on 5.7 smoothly. Which error concrete do you get

Comment: I get SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from total' at line 8

Comment: Your code works: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n9waizvimnAiQpHdUfwJgQ/0

Comment: The error message indicates that mysql probably has a problem with separating the two sql statements. Try to run them separately, not in one go.

Comment: If you're trying to execute the code via an api/dll call in a programming language, be aware that many libraries do not allow multiple statements in a single "execute".

Comment: I have tried what you told me. If I only runs the first statement I get INSERT, CREATE command denied to user 'my_user' for table 'total'. So I think that is a permission issue, isnt, it?